# Java MySQL Connection with SSL Authority Certificate

Tags: java, mysql, ssl, jdbc

I am trying to connect using Java Rest `WebService` to a `JDBC`.

First I connected successfully using MySQL Workbench with username and password and one extra detail, I needed to add a "Path to Certificate Authority file for SSL" and worked, I was able to connect and use.I have the certificate to use the database remote.

Now I am trying to connect using Java and that is the way I am trying:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConexaoBD {
    // Define o Metodo de Conexao quando a classe � chamada
    static {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public Connection obtemConexao() throws SQLException {
        System.getProperties().setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","/mysqlcertificate.pem");
        return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://myHost", "myUsername", "myPassword");                                  
    }
}
```

I research about put useSSL=true in the URL but didn't work or this `system.getproperties`, I also p the `.pem` file in the project package and inside my class package (because I don't know what is the place I need to put the file).

What should I do to connect? Without this SSL, the database refuse my connection, and I am trying to connect in another class this way:

```
Connection conn = null;
Statement stm = null;
try {
    ConexaoBD bd = new ConexaoBD();
    conn = bd.obtemConexao();
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

My case was similar, but not same. I could connect to MySQL from workbench but not from my code. The only option selected in workbench was useSSL if Available. 
The code below worked for me in that case.

```
private String db_server = BaseMethods.getSystemData("db_server");
private String db_user = BaseMethods.getSystemData("db_user");
private String db_password = BaseMethods.getSystemData("db_password");

private void connectToDb() throws Exception {
    String jdbcDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://" + db_server +
        "?verifyServerCertificate=false" +
        "&useSSL=true" +
        "&requireSSL=true";
    System.setProperty(jdbcDriver, "");
    Class.forName(jdbcDriver).newInstance();

    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, db_user, db_password);
    Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
}
```